# Line breaks dissapearing in HTML submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I am having an issues where line breaks are dissapearing along a form submission path. Here is my scenario.

I have a multi-line textbox (2 rows) on a html web page. 
When the form is submitted, jquery retrieves the value of the textbox using

```
$("#txtboxid").val();
```

When I inspect the value using Chrome's debugger I can see that line breaks are in there.

(test data was `a\r\nb\r\nc\r\nd`)

I then get jQuery to post the data using the following JavaScript.

```
function postData(to, params) {
    var myForm = document.createElement("form");
    myForm.method = "post";
    myForm.action = to;
    for (var k in params) {
        var myInput = document.createElement("input");
        myInput.setAttribute("name", k);
        myInput.setAttribute("value", params[k]);
        myForm.appendChild(myInput);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(myForm);
    myForm.submit();
    document.body.removeChild(myForm);
}
```

When I then inspect the posted values in ASP.NET using the NameValueCollection from Request.Form, there do not seem to be any line breaks or line break characters.

```
eg = string textboxValue = Request.Form["myTextBox"];
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Did you try to see if the actual HTTP request contains the line breaks? use firebug or fiddler to inspect the request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected behavior: you're taking data from multiline `<textarea>` elements and putting it in single-line `<input>` elements. Therefore, line breaks are lost.

Try creating `<textarea>` elements instead of `<input>` elements. For instance, using jQuery:

```
function postData(to, params)
{
    var myForm = $("<form>").attr({
        method: "post",
        action: to
    });
    $.each(params, function(key, value) {
        $("<textarea>").attr("name", key).val(value).appendTo(myForm);
    });
    myForm.appendTo("body").submit().remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data in coming from multi-line textboxes but you are creating INPUT elements which I guess dont accept newlines. That could be an issue.